# drawLines function works but lines dissapear after the end of loading

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a function that draw lines in an array. I'm calling this function in a loop, so that every family of my array as a line.  When I execute the program step by step, I can see that the lines are well drawn but when the document has finished to load, the lines are erased.

I call the function draw on the ngAfterViewInit.

I don't put my function code because it's not necessary, the function works well. I think it's a problem of lifecycle but I don't know how to resolve it.

This is my HTML. The lines are drawn in the td.

```
<table *ngIf="listeFamilles">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let f of listeFamilles">
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px;">{{ f.nom }}</th>
      <td  id="{{f.nom}}"  style="vertical-align: top;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is where I call my function :

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.serviceFam.getAllFamilles()
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.listeFamilles = data;
          for (let f of this.listeFamilles) {
            //console.log(this.listeAffaires._embedded.affaires[0]);
            console.log(f.nom);
            this.draw("#" + f.nom, this.arriel1, {dateDimension: false, color: "teal", labelFormat: "%Y"})
          }
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

Here is my code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tds4sv

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to reproduce this? Your code looks fine. It must be something else.

Comment: I have created a stackblitz, it works fine when I get the data from an array. I think it's when I get the data from the API where it bugs

Comment: Is your API maybe returning the data twice? The first time, it has data, and the second time it has an empty array?

Comment: How can be the data returned twice if I call the function only once ?

Comment: can you please show us your data that come from your API? your code and sample data looks good.